# how to filter the values ​correctly, by the beginning of the sentence? Using Pattern from Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-file

I have the follow string for filter :

**action=Received type=Event IdService=45221**

I try this and get first :

=%{DATA:action}\s

```
{
  "action": "Received"
}
```

But When i try continue

=%{DATA:action} =%{DATA:type}\s

it happens this

```
{}
```

How i must change my pattern for get all values from string ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume all of the text in the part of the field that you are matching against. When you use `=%{DATA:action}\s` that matches on the first = and consumes `Received` using DATA, and the pattern ends with whitespace.

When you use `=%{DATA:action} =%{DATA:type}\s` it matches `Received` and the whitespace, and then fails, because the next text is `type`, not `=`.

You could use `action=%{DATA:action}\stype=%{DATA:type}\s` or even

```
grok {
    break_on_match => false
    match => {
        "message" => [
            "action=%{DATA:action}\s",
            "type=%{DATA:type}\s",
            "IdService=%{NUMBER:id}\b"
        ]
    }
}
```

which will match those fields even if they are re-ordered or some are missing.